# Research group at/of University?

Tags: prepositions

What is the correct formulation:

> Prof. X research group **at** the University of Y

or

> Prof. X research group **of** the University of X

?

Comment: *Prof. X's research group at the University of X* and *Prof. X's research group of the University of Y* are both correct.

Comment: Which one is more common or does sound nicer?

Comment: If it is merely *at* the university, it might simply be using the university as a venue (e.g. a visiting group).

Comment: Both of my suggestions mean different things. In the *at* example, the team is visiting whereas in the *of* example, they belong to the Y university.

Comment: So if they belong to the Y university, they cannot be at the university?

Comment: No, V means that 'of' (belong to) is stronger than 'at.' If they belong to, they are probably 'at' the school, but not the reverse.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to say!

- The group at/*of the University of Nebraska has come up with a new formula to cure AIDS.

---

1. **"at"** - the group has come to the university and did something extraordinary there but they are a group of or from another university or maybe just a group all by themselves.
2. **"of"** - the group that belongs to the university, works for it, that is a part of the university did something extraordinary.